# В чём здесь ошибка?

Tags: java, java-8

```
    public class Main {
    class Vehicle {
        int passengers; 
        int fuelcap;    
        int mpg;

        void range() {
            System.out.println("Range is " + fuelcap * mpg);
        }
    }

    class AddMeth {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Vehicle minivan = new Vehicle();
            Vehicle sportscar = new Vehicle();

            minivan.passengers = 7;
            minivan.fuelcap = 16;
            minivan.mpg = 21;

            sportscar.passengers = 2;
            sportscar.fuelcap = 14;
            sportscar.mpg = 12;

            System.out.print("Minivan can carry " + minivan.passengers + ". ");

            minivan.range(); 

            System.out.print("Sportscar can carry " + sportscar.passengers +  ". ");

            sportscar.range(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код. При компиляции выдаёт ошибки:

```
Error:(17, 31) java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(18, 33) java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
Error:(16, 28) java: Illegal static declaration in inner class Main.AddMeth
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
```

Comment: В тексте ошибки четко и понятно написано, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска программы внешний (единственный в файле публичный) класс должен называться так же, как и файл, и он должен содержать статический метод

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Делаете здесь, что надо   
}
```

Этот метод является точкой входа в программу. Статические методы не могут обращаться к нестатическим переменным или методам. Следовательно, вам нужно либо все методы и переменные объявлять как статические, либо в коде статического метода создать экземпляр какого-либо класса (можно того же самого), и вызывать нестатический метод этого экземпляра, который будет делать всё, что вам надо, используя нестатические члены  (переменные и методы экземпляра). Например, так:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) { // Точка входа
    new Main().run(args);      // Создаем объект и вызываем его метод run() 
  }

  int i, j; // Переменные экземпляра 

  void run(String... args) {  // Метод экземпляра
    // Делаете здесь, что надо   
    i = j = 123; // В методе экземпляра можно использовать переменные экземпляра 
    anotherInstanceMethod(); // И вызывать другие методы экземпляра  
  }

  void anotherInstanceMethod() {
    System.out.format("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
  }

} // public class Main {
```

Ну и советую всё-таки почитать учебники, тогда у вас таких вопросов (за которые, как видите, здесь минусуют) возникать не будет -- там все это написано.

Comment: Не работает. При создании экземпляра, пишет что метод отстутсвует.

Comment: Да, пардон, описка. В строке, где создается объект, должно быть `new Main().run(args);` -- в спешке я пропустил скобки и точку с запятой. Исправил текст ответа. Но все-таки если бы вы последовали моему совету и почитали-таки учебники, то у вас и этого вопроса не возникло бы. Это азы синтаксиса, и если вы хотите научиться программировать,то без его знания вам не обойтись.